# Altering a non clustered index in a sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a unique non-clustered index on a sybase table which includes 4 columns:
col1, col2, col3 and col4.

I want to drop one of the columns from the table.

I don't want to drop and recreate the index.

Can I alter the index to not consider this column?

Comment: There used to be (11.0) a mention in `alter table drop column` that the `drop` would fail if there was an index defined on that column. As of 15.0, this mention is no longer present; so I wonder if the `alter table drop column` would not work without explicitly recreating the index...

Answer (score 1):

Shortly no.

You can only alter "database", "role" or "table" in sybase. With using "alter table" you can modify only columns.

Adding or removing a column to index causes an index to be re-created. Sybase doesn't like "modify" something if it has to be re-created so you have to drop and create the index.